# How to match geospatial data using GPS coordinates?

Tags: python, r, match, geospatial, feature-engineering

I have data collected from different devices A, B, C and all data were recorded in the format of

```
Table 1 from device A:
Longtitude Latitude Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
XX.xxx     XX.xxx   10.00    20.00    30.00   
---
many rows
```

```
Table 2 from device B:
Longtitude Latitude Feature3 Feature4 Feature5
XX.xxx     XX.xxx   1.00    2.00    3.00    
---
many rows
```

```
Table 3 from device C:
Longtitude Latitude FeatureX FeatureY
XX.xxx     XX.xxx   5        6
---
many rows
```

How can I get a table recording all features from the nearest location? so that I can make regression using the features. R or Python Prefered. Thanks.

```
Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Feature3 Feature4 Feature5 FeatureX FeatureY
10.00    20.00    30.00    1.00     2.00     3.00     5        6
---
Many Rows
```

Comment: Share the code you have written till now

Comment: Currently, I do it on small data samples manually with Excel using formulas to minimize the GPS coordinates. It is not a good way when encountering large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

The [sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html#geopandas-sjoin-nearest) function of [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org) looks interesting.

Comment: Thank you. I found a very helpful tutorial that solved my problem. https://autogis-site.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/L3/06_nearest-neighbor-faster.html